TCL performance: One billion loop
I was following the 1 billion iteration challenge launched on Twitter (https://github.com/bddicken/languages), so I decided to see how TCL would behave. However, I had a very unpleasant surprise. While the python code took 91.16s on my machine, the equivalent TCL code took 778.70s. Below are the two codes. The python code was taken from the challenge repository. I'm not a big TCL expert, so the question is: Is there any optimization possible?
TCL code.
set u [expr {int([lindex $argv 0])}]
set r [expr {int(rand()*10000)}]
array set a {}

for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {
    set a($i) 0
    for {set j 0} {$j < 100000} {incr j} {
      set a($i) [expr {$a($i) + $j % $u}]
    }
    set a($i) [expr {$a($i) + $r}]
}

puts $a($r)                

Python code
import sys
import random

def main():
    u = int(sys.argv[1])         # Get an input number from the command line
    r = random.randint(0, 10000) # Get a random number 0 <= r < 10k
    a  = [0] * 10000             # Array of 10k elements initialized to 0
    for i in range(10000):       # 10k outer loop iterations
      for j in range(100000):    # 100k inner loop iterations, per outer loop iteration
        a[i] += j%u              # Simple sum
      a[i] += r                  # Add a random value to each element in array
    print(a[r])                  # Print out a single element from the arra
main()



Python 3.12.7
TCL 8.6 (little changes between tcl 8.6 and 9)
My machine is an Aspire 3 notebook, Ryzen 7 with 24G of RAM
O.S Arch Linux

EDIT:
I tried some code changes without major performance changes, such as:

Use of list
Use of array
Use of for
Use of while
Switch TCL version.

I don't want them to "optimize my code", because this code is somewhat useless and won't change the way I use TCL in my tasks. But as I already read somewhere that TCL and Python have similar performance, I found it strange that such basic code would show such a difference. I think it may be some details in my implementation.
So I would like to know what those more experienced in TCL can teach about this.

If your question is "please optimise my code for me", it is not suitable for StackOverflow. You could try on https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/ or share what you tried to improve performance, if you're having trouble getting it to work, or if you need help understanding why it doesn't perform as well as expected.

Before posting on Code Review please read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users and How do I ask a good question? first.

What's the problem with my question? It's a lot of free hostility. If you don't like it or don't know, just don't respond, like I do.

Maybe try putting the working code inside a 'proc' like the python example. The Tcl bytecode compiler might do better than trying to reinterpret everything all the time.

wow, this tip really made a difference! thanks.

You'll find this page interesting: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Performance

I love Tcl, but this type of language benchmark is testing a use case that Tcl shouldn't be used for.  That's not to say that most of your system shouldn't be Tcl (if that makes sense), just that tight inner loops like this that boil down to a few integer instructions are completely unsuitable for this sort of language.
If you find yourself snowed in one day with nothing to do - make a lot of coffee (in a thermos, this will take a while) and step through the c code in a debugger as the Tcl interp runs just one iteration of each of the nested loops (set the iteration count to 1 and 1).  I've done this (or at least for similar cases), and I think you'll leave with a deep appreciation of the cost of the abstraction layer that Tcl is presenting.  What will also become painfully apparent is that most of the work that is actually done in an example like this is managing the bytecode execution - a vanishingly small portion of the work is the actual computation that the code performs.
The reason that this kind of benchmark is useless to evaluate Tcl performance is that the results you get from it don't extrapolate to meaningful performance insights into real work that you'd actually do in Tcl, even if you, like me, reach for Tcl first, and in more situations than may be strictly justifiable.
Also note that if you run Tcl code like this in a docker environment, the performance is MUCH worse - around a factor of 2 in my testing.  That comes from docker enabling some speculative execution vulnerability mitigations that aren't enabled by default on Linux (because their performance impact is large).  Any language with the kind of conditional-jumps-based bytecode dispatch that Tcl uses is affected by this (python too), but Tcl is especially hard hit.
Rant aside, if the computation in question was somehow needed in the context of some bigger Tcl codebase, I'd drop to C just for that bit.  C expresses that code as clearly and tersely as Tcl, so there is no complexity or comprehensibility advantage to implementing it in the higher level language.
From the very beginnings of the language it was designed to play nicely with C, so there is very little friction to doing that.  Mainly the friction comes from having to pre-compile the C extension for each platform you use, but I built a package to take care of all that (jitc).  There are others like it (tcctcl, critcl).  Doing that, and comparing the performance yields some interesting insights:
package require jitc    ;# Just-In-Time C: https://github.com/cyanogilvie/jitc

proc tclbusy {n r} {
    set a {}

    for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {
        set x 0
        for {set j 0} {$j < 100000} {incr j} {
            incr x [expr {$j % $n}]
        }
        lappend a [incr x $r]
    }

    lindex $a $r
}

set compile_start   [clock microseconds]
jitc::bind busybusybusy {
    code {
        OBJCMD(busywork) {
            int         code = TCL_OK;
            Tcl_WideInt n, r;
            Tcl_Obj*    values = NULL;

            enum {A_cmd, A_N, A_R, A_objc};
            CHECK_ARGS_LABEL(finally, code, "u r");
            TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_GetWideIntFromObj(interp, objv[A_N], &n));
            TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_GetWideIntFromObj(interp, objv[A_R], &r));

            replace_tclobj(&values, Tcl_NewListObj(10000, NULL));
            for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
                Tcl_WideInt x = 0;
                for (int j=0; j<100000; j++) x += j % n;
                x += r;
                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, values, Tcl_NewWideIntObj(x)));
            }

            Tcl_Obj*    chosen = NULL;
            TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_ListObjIndex(interp, values, r, &chosen));
            Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, chosen);

        finally:
            replace_tclobj(&values, NULL);
            return code;
        }
    }
} busywork

jitc::bind busybusybusy2 {
    code {
        OBJCMD(busywork) {
            int             code = TCL_OK;
            Tcl_WideInt     n, r;
            Tcl_WideInt*    values = NULL;

            enum {A_cmd, A_N, A_R, A_objc};
            CHECK_ARGS_LABEL(finally, code, "u r");
            TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_GetWideIntFromObj(interp, objv[A_N], &n));
            TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_GetWideIntFromObj(interp, objv[A_R], &r));

            values = ckalloc(10000 * sizeof Tcl_WideInt);
            for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
                Tcl_WideInt x = 0;
                for (int j=0; j<100000; j++) x += j % n;
                x += r;
                values[i] = x;
            }

            Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewWideIntObj(values[r]));

        finally:
            if (values) {
                ckfree(values);
                values = NULL;
            }
            return code;
        }
    }
} busywork
puts "Compile 2 c versions: [format %.3f [expr {([clock microseconds]-$compile_start)/1e3}]] ms"

set r   [expr {int(rand()*10000)}]

puts "\nTcl version: accumulate state in a list with lappend:"
puts [timerate {
    puts [tclbusy [lindex $argv 0] $r]
}]

puts "\nAccumulate state in a Tcl list:"
puts [timerate {
    puts [busybusybusy [lindex $argv 0] $r]
}]

puts "\nAccumulate state in a c array:"
puts [timerate {
    puts [busybusybusy2 [lindex $argv 0] $r]
}]

Produces (in an optimised Tcl 8.7 interp on my i7-12800H laptop, Linux, not containerised):
Compile 2 c versions: 9.373 ms

Tcl version: accumulate state in a list with lappend:
2050558
39840865 µs/# 1 # 0.025 #/sec 39840.865 net-ms

Accumulate state in a Tcl list:
2050558
2093536 µs/# 1 # 0.478 #/sec 2093.536 net-ms

Accumulate state in a c array:
2050558
2092008 µs/# 1 # 0.478 #/sec 2092.008 net-ms

Note how similar the times are for both c implementations - the first one most closely mirrors the Tcl implementation in that it accumulates the state in a Tcl list, and creates a Tcl_Obj representing each of the 10,000 results.
The second c implementation uses a plain c array with unboxed integer values, and only boxes the picked out ($r) result.
The performance is pretty much indistinguishable.  But since the work done in that depth is washed out by a factor of 100,000 by the innermost loop, it shouldn't really be surprising.  This is also why the Tcl implementations using associative arrays and lists show no meaningful performance difference (unless access into that structure is in the inner loop).

I approve of embedding C inside Tcl. It's a very Tcl thing to do.

Very good, thanks for the explanation! This approach to incorporating c within TCL is really cool, I'll use it when I need more performance. Really, this code is "useless", but I wanted to test where I could take idiomatic TCL in relation to Python. An embedded JIT would take TCL to compete with go, java or lua JIT in terms of performance for these cases.

Yup, I'm working on a Tcl jit of sorts (off and on in the rare gaps I get between work emergencies).  DKF and KBK have done great work in this area already: tclquadcode.  The approach I'm playing with is in a different direction though - primarily reworking the bytecode engine to avoid the crippling docker tax.

The primary considerations here are to put the code inside a procedure and to switch from an associative array to a list (as that's backed by a C array and not a string-indexed hash table); though lindex and lset look longer, they're very fast operations. We can initialize the list with lrepeat but that probably won't make such a huge difference to the overall speed. (Extracting the size and count parameters to be arguments just makes for more convenient testing.)
proc main {u {size 10000} {count 100000}} {
    set r [expr {int(rand() * $size)}]
    set a [lrepeat $size 0]

    for {set i 0} {$i < $size} {incr i} {
       for {set j 0} {$j < $count} {incr j} {
           lset a $i [expr {[lindex $a $i] + $j % $u}]
       }
       lset a $i [expr {[lindex $a $i] + $r}]
    }

    return [lindex $a $r]
}

puts [main {*}$argv]

In this case, we can go further by using a working variable in the inner loop, which helps quite a bit:
proc main {u {size 10000} {count 100000}} {
    set r [expr {int(rand() * $size)}]
    set a [lrepeat $size 0]

    for {set i 0} {$i < $size} {incr i} {
       set v 0
       for {set j 0} {$j < $count} {incr j} {
           incr v [expr {$j % $u}]
       }
       lset a $i [incr v $r]
    }

    return [lindex $a $r]
}

puts [main {*}$argv]

Tcl doesn't require you to explicitly make u be an integer; after the first time through the loop, it will either be an integer or you'll have errored.

A possible solution in Tcl 9.0 is this:
proc main {u {size 10000} {count 100000}} {
    set r [expr {int(rand() * $size)}]
    set a [lrepeat $size 0]

    foreach i [lseq $size] {
       set v 0
       foreach j [lseq $count] {
           incr v [expr {$j % $u}]
       }
       lset a $i [incr v $r]
    }

    return [lindex $a $r]
}

puts [main {*}$argv]

The lseq command is really a generator expression (to use Python terminology). This appears to be slightly faster (but I can't compare it directly as I'm using a debug build right now).

I had already tested using lists, and it was always slower than dict and array. I believe it is due to the immutability of the lists in TCL. Using a variable instead of accessing the array index improved from 131s to 118s. But I don't know if this "mischaracterize" the proposed challenge. Anyway, it's already very close to the python version.

The exact details matter a lot. The key to getting speed is limiting memory allocations and type shimmering; arrays are definitely more inclined to that than lists in this case. (Also, don't test with an Apple-provided tclsh; they enable dtrace probes and they have a lot of performance overheads.)

Lists can be modified in place by lset, provided the list is unshared (commonly true).

What should I use instead of tclsh?

Build your own from source or use someone else's distribution. It's a special debugging feature of the Apple build and nobody else uses it. All debugging options tend to degrade performance...

Following @aMike's tip, I added the code inside a proc so that TCL could optimize the bytecode. This resulted in a significant improvement in performance. Now runs in twice the time of Python.
TCL 8.6
array for: 154s
array while: 152s
dict for: 197s
dict while: 200s
list for: 363s
list while: 364s


Try using incr var_name integer to instead of set var_name [expr {$var_name + $integer}] .   This updates the variable "in-place"

with this tip it went to 131s

You could also try using upvar before looping - search for "indirected array" on this page https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Performance

I understand that this would only apply in case of indirection, but my array variable is always accessed directly. Am I missing something?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what they mean by "indirected array" but I thought it meant using a variable for the key like you are doing. Maybe it means something else. Anyway, just thought it was worth a shot.

The "indirected array" being talked about is writing via set ${foo}($bar) $grill, which requires reparsing things and is horribly slow, whereas upvar $foo v; set v($bar) $grill is saner and faster (especially if the upvar can be factored out).

This is the fastest version so far. 110ms
TCL 8.6
* array for: 112ms
* array while: 110ms
* dict for: 117ms
* dict while: 143ms
* list for: 128ms
* list while: 138ms

proc run_array_while {n} {
    set u [expr {int($n)}]
    set r [expr {int(rand()*10000)}]
    array set values {}
    set i 0
    while {$i < 10000} {
      set j 0
      set x $i
      while {$j < 100000} {
        incr x [expr {$j % $u}]
        incr j
      }
      incr x $r
      set values($i) $x
      incr i
    }

    puts $values($r)
}




The array set can probably be omitted. Won't make much difference to the speed, which will be dominated by the loops.
